# Table not mapped using EF code first approach

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, code-first

I'd like to use `EF code first approach`. I added the database and I generate the tables . Then I added this class

```
  public class Invitation
    {

      
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool State { get; set; }

        public string Mail { get; set; }

        public string Tel { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Qr_code { get; set; }
  
    }
```

I run these command then  :

> add-migrations second
>
> update-database

the `Up` and `Down` methods of the second class migration are empty!! and no table is added to the database.

**The context**

```
 public class ApplicationContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
         public ApplicationContext()
            :base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationContext>());
        }

        public static ApplicationContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

So I need to know

1. What is the reason of this problem?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see any `DbSet` values...did you forget some code?

Comment: Yepp, the `DbSet<Invitation>` value is missing. That's the reason for _Up()_ and _Down()_ being empty.

Comment: @MarkC. Yes i forget to add it in the context, post your commentas an aswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to tell Entity Framework about the new table that you want added (`DbSet<Invitation>`)

Once you add this, Entity Framework should add the table(s) you want added in the Migration script, respectively.

In summation, you would need to add this line :

```
public DbSet<Invitation> Invitations { get; set; }
```

and/or

```
public IDbSet<Invitation> Invitations { get; set; }
```

and run another Migration Script.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following into your ApplicationContext class

```
public DbSet<Invitation> Invitations { get; set; }
```

Then running;

```
Enable-Migration
Add-Migration note_of_changes
Update-Database
```

Comment: Or instead of "changes" you could add a more meaningful note "AddDbSet" =P

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create an initial migration. If this is your **first** migration (note that this will clear your existing migration history so only use if you're happy to discard your existing migration history)

1. Delete your Migrations folder in the solution
2. Remove your changes (remove the reference to the new table from your `DbContext`). Note that `-IgnoreChanges` could well make this step redundant but I can't say for certain.
3. Remove the MigrationHistory table from your database (it most likely won't exist but you can go ahead and delete it if it is)

Now enable migrations (in package manager console)

```
Enable-Migrations
```

Then create your initial migration. This will create a migration matching your existing schema with empty methods

```
Add-Migration Initial –IgnoreChanges
Update-Database
```

Then update your `DbContext` with your new table reference and make any other changes you need to and do

```
Add-Migration MyChanges
Update-Database
```

That should apply the changes to the database. Some [more info over at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx) if you need it.

Comment: In the OP's question they said : `I added the database and I generate the tables`.. Assuming this was already done

Comment: I don't the think initial database creation actually creates a migration. I've run into issues with the first migration not being picked up properly (with similar symptoms of empty methods) which got fixed by creating an initial migration as noted. Having said that, the issue does appear to be the missing `DbSet` as you said in this case. I was planning to leave my answer here due to slight ambiguity but I can delete it it clouds the issue?

Comment: Really? Were there any exceptions or anything? I don't think you should delete it at all! It's very possible that other people run into that scenario as well (just don't think that was the case for this question)

Comment: Yeah no exceptions at all. Gave the impression of working but just didn't pick up any changes. I'll leave it here then, might help somebody out in the future.