# How to recreate a migration script

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have tried as below :

1. removed all the generated scripts which it relates to model on the `Migrations` folder.
2. removed all the entries whcih it relates to model on the `__MigrationHistory` table.

But it creates like this when I run:

```
PM> Add-Migration "Added_Investors_Table"
```

**Generated migration script**

```
 public partial class Added_Investors_Table : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {

        }

        public override void Down()
        {

        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
    [Table("Investors")]
    public class Investor : FullAuditedEntity
    {

        public virtual int AmountCommitted { get; set; }

        public virtual decimal PercentageOfDeal { get; set; }

        public virtual decimal AmountSpentToDate { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext.cs**

```
public class IpDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User>
    {
        /* Define an IDbSet for each entity of the application */

        public virtual IDbSet<Investor> Investors { get; set; }

        public IpDbContext() : base("Default")
        {

        }
   }
```

Do you know why it does not recreate a migration script as usual ? What are the other places, should I remove this model other than the above mentioned 2 places ?

**Note :** The above mentioned table is a new one.I have successfully created script first time.But due to some changes and etc.. I need to recreate it again.But it does not work.But If I change existing model then it gives change set script.Very strange no ? I don't know where's the problem is..

Comment: can you show more code? like your DbContext class?

Comment: @tmg Done that.Please see it.

Comment: I've run into something similar in the past and got around it by creating an initial migration with `-IgnoreChanges`. Have a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916150/table-not-mapped-using-ef-code-first-approach/36916941#36916941) for the steps. Might work for you.

Comment: @Tone I cannot do that.B'cos I have around 50+ tables with all full of data.The above mentioned table is a new one.I have successfully created script first time.But due to some changes and etc.. I need to recreate it again.But it does not work.But If I change existing model then it gives change set.Very strange no ?

Comment: The problem is that EF stores a snapshot of your _Current_ model in the **last** migration you scaffold. The VERY last migration is not necessarily the last migration that did something with `Investor`. Thus, your VERY last EF migration contains information about the `Investor` entity, even after deleting any previous code migration or `__MigrationHistory` entry related to `Investor`. You have to find a way to trick EF to believe it has a model without `Investor` in it, and then create a new migration to scaffold `Investor` again

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you don't mind recreating the `Investor` entity and the corresponding table, but **you don't want to modify anything else**. If so, I think you can, **carefully**, try the following:

1. Backup your database (use a prod copy or dev database anyway)
2. Restore your previous Migration scripts back into your `Migrations` folder
3. Restore the `__MigrationHistoryTable`
4. Keep the migration script classes but remove the DDL code that is related to the `Investor` entity (e.g. If you have a migration to add `Investor`, the `up` and `down` methods should be empty for that migration)
5. Remove the `Investor` entity and its configuration from the `DbContext` and generate a new migration using the `-IgnoreChanges` switch. Let's say this migration is called **RemoveInvestorMigration**. This one should also have empty `up` and `down` methods due to the `-IgnoreChanges` switch
6. Apply the **RemoveInvestorMigration** migration to your (development) database via `Update-Database`. **Now EF believes you removed the `Investor` entity (and you did, somehow)**
7. Restore the `Investor` entity and its configuration into the `DbContext` again
8. Generate a new migration. Let's call this one **RestoreInvestorMigration**. This one should generate the proper `up` and `down` methods that create the `Investor` entity. You must have some `CreateTable` code here, otherwise something is wrong
9. Apply the **RestoreInvestorMigration** and you are done

The trick is to *make EF believe*, but you have to be careful, because *it will believe*

By the way, whenever you need it, you can run `Update-Database` with the `-Script` switch, so that EF will show you the SQL code generated in order to update the DB after applying a migration. This will not apply the migration (i.e. it won't execute the SQL code). This way, you can see what EF would do should you choose to apply the migration

Comment: I gave a temporarily solution for my client.I'll look at your solution on coming days and will give you my feedback.Thanks.